# Is there a name for the layout algorithm for visualizing git branch history?

Tags: git, visualization

Is there a name for the graph layouting algorithm that is 
used for visualizing branch history in i.e. like in `gitk` or even `git log --graph`. 
How is this class of layouting algorithms called?

Comment: Both `gitk` and `git log --graph` do a simple topological sort (making sure children come out before parents) and otherwise just draw connecting lines, which is not very fancy. I'm not sure this has a name (other than the word *upward* to describe the one-way directional arrows). See ftp://ftp.cs.brown.edu/pub/papers/compgeo/draw-tutorial-1.pdf for an introduction to some of the issues and terms for fancier algorithms.

Comment: Maybe algorithms on DAG, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph.

Comment: @torek : You need to at least allocate a column to track the open branches for each row when sequencing the output of ```git log```. To avoid clutter I guess you would like to minimize the column count and free space between colums..

Comment: @KonradEisele: true, and `git log --graph` adds an extra constraint: the first-parent connection line goes straight down from the commit, second-parent lines go down-and-right using backslash. This then adds annoying (and ugly) cases of reversal of the diagonal connecting lines as needed.

Comment: @torek : so when following the branches from bottom up a new branch could push others to the side or be allocated beside the existing branches. Branches could be forces to be straight columns or there could be a bending criteria (flow around) or break criteria (continue at side) for branches . Etc. I wonder weather there is a general type of layouting algorithm for DAG that matches this. Really ideal would be an iterative algorithm that adapts to the reverse output of ```git log``` .